# how to deal with compression when using pydantic for deserialization and serialization

Tags: python, pydantic

Consider the following simple example of a class called `TableConfigs`:

```
import pydantic
from enum import Enum


class TimeUnit(str, Enum):
    days = "days"
    hours = "hours"
    minutes = "minutes"
    seconds = "seconds"


class TableNames(str, Enum):
    surname = "surname"
    weather = "weather"
    traffic = "traffic"


class TimeQuantity(pydantic.BaseModel):
    value: int
    unit: TimeUnit


class TableConfig(pydantic.BaseModel):
    on: list[str]
    time_quantities: list[TimeQuantity]


class TableConfigs(pydantic.BaseModel):
    values: dict[TableNames, TableConfig]
```

As I am using pydantic I can easily deseralize/serialize an instance of the class:

```
tc = TableConfigs(
    values={
        "weather": TableConfig(
            on=["city"],
            time_quantities=[
                TimeQuantity(value=60, unit=TimeUnit.days),
                TimeQuantity(value=7, unit=TimeUnit.days),
                TimeQuantity(value=1, unit=TimeUnit.seconds),
            ],
        )
    }
)

tc_copy = TableConfigs(**tc.model_dump())
```

The json representation leaves lot of room for what I called compression, as the result of the model_dump

```
{'values': 
   {
      <TableNames.weather: 'weather'>: 
      {
         'on': ['city'],
         'time_quantities': [
               {'value': 60, 'unit': <TimeUnit.days: 'days'>
               },
               {'value': 7, 'unit': <TimeUnit.days: 'days'>
               },
               {'value': 1, 'unit': <TimeUnit.seconds: 'seconds'>
               }
            ]
      }
   }
}
```

could without loss of information be written as (encoded):

```
{'tables': 'weather:city;60d,7d,1s'}
```

Which can be achieved by adding a `field_serializer` and a `model_serializer`:

```
class TableConfigs(pydantic.BaseModel):
    values: dict[TableNames, TableConfig]

    @pydantic.field_serializer("values")
    def serialize_values(self, values: dict[TableNames, TableConfig]) -> str:
        s = ""
        for i, table_name in enumerate(values):
            if i > 0:
                s += "#"
            s += table_name + ":"
            s += ",".join(values[table_name].on) + ";"
            for time_quantity in values[table_name].time_quantities:
                s += str(time_quantity.value) + time_quantity.unit + ","
            s = s[:-1]

        s = (
            s.replace("days", "d")
            .replace("hours", "h")
            .replace("minutes", "m")
            .replace("seconds", "s")
        )
        return s

    @pydantic.model_serializer
    def ser_model(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {"tables": f"{self.serialize_values(self.values)}"}


tc = TableConfigs(
    values={
        "weather": TableConfig(
            on=["city"],
            time_quantities=[
                TimeQuantity(value=60, unit=TimeUnit.days),
                TimeQuantity(value=7, unit=TimeUnit.days),
                TimeQuantity(value=1, unit=TimeUnit.seconds),
            ],
        )
    }
)

print(tc.model_dump())
```

prints

```
{'tables': 'weather:city;60d,7d,1s}
```

But how can I now again deserialize? I guess I have to write a function which takes the compressed form and converts it into a dictionary which is then passed to the regular pydantic functions used for deserialization.

Comment: Not answering your question, but why complicate? You want to compress json? Zip it. Then unzip it when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

As @zvone put it in the comment, if you want to take less bandwidth or disk space, just apply a knowb compression algorithm, readily available from Python itself, on your final JSON file. These compress close to maximum theoretical levels, and have been hardened through decades to cover all edge cases and also on the security side:

```
import zlib

...
compressed_bytes = zlib.compress(json_string.encode("utf-8"))

# And to decompress the binary data:

json_data = zlib.decompress(compressed_bytes).decode("utf-8")
```

On the other hand, what you want to achieve might sense if you want a more compact file that can pack more information in the same screen real-state, and then it become more confortable for human editing.

On the other hand, creating such an "ad hoc" extra encoding mean you'd loose support of all the echo-system for JSON data out there - you are basically using another encoding on top of json for data from your classes.

So, unlike Python stdlib's datamodel, Pydantic do not generate an `__init__` function for your models: you can then write a `__init__` which will parse your custom string into the standard JSON format expected by Pydanditic, and call `super().__init__()` with this "pre-deserialized" data.

You will need to write an `__init__` method for your `TableConfigs` class, which verifies if the value it got for the `values` field is a dictionary, or a string. If it is a string, call another method that will "uncompress" it, using a similar logic you used to compression (sorry, I won't write that code for you, but I guess you might can do it. Don't forget writting unit-tests for both encoding and decoding your model).

```
...
class TableConfigs(pydantic.BaseModel):
    values: dict[TableNames, TableConfig]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if "values" in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs["values"], str):
           kwargs["values"] = self.deserialize_values(kwargs["values"])
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def deserialize_values(self, values):
        tb_name, fields = values.split(":")
        fields = fields.split(";")
        # follow code for reconstructiong the json for each table, as encoded:
        new_values = {}
        if tb_name == "weather":
            new_values["on"] = fields[0]
            time_qtys = fields[1].split(",")
            new_time_qtys = []
            for time_qty in time_qtys:
                 new_time_qtys.append(...)  # <- your decoding code goes here
            new_values["time_quantities"] = new_time_qtys
            ...
        elif tbname == "whatever":
            ...
        return new_values

    @pydantic.field_serializer("values")
    def serialize_values(self, values: dict[TableNames, TableConfig]) -> str:
        s = ""
        ...

...
```